# Regex to find the "+some text except + " @+some text+news format

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text:

```
"@cbcnews used to have journalistic integrity... what happened"
```

I also have another one like below:

```
"they used to have journalistic integrity... what happened" @cbcnews
```

or

```
@cbcnews "they used to have journalistic integrity... what happened"
```

I want to check if the text pattern is

```
"+some text except + " @+some text+news
```

or

```
@+some text+news+ "+some text except + "
```

like exactly what we have in the second and third sentences but not in the first one.

I know how to write a code to check this but I am wondering if there is any regular expression to do that. Can anyone help?

Update:

My code:

```
EXAMPLE_TEST = "\"they used to have journalistic integrity... what happened\" @cbcnews";
System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST.matches("@\S+(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)"));
```

Comment: Could you please formulate the requirements, too? Do you need to match a `@txt`-like word somewhere outside of paired double quotes?

Comment: @stribizhev thanks a lot for answering yes exaxly this is what I want, also here is my java code from your previous code :String EXAMPLE_TEST = "\"they used to have journalistic integrity... what happened\" @cbcnews";
  System.out.println(EXAMPLE_TEST.matches("@\S+(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)"));

Comment: @VinceEmigh please see update

Comment: @Pshemo see update please, since I am not familiar with regx I was not sure if it is possible to do it with regex or not

Comment: @HamedMinaee Thank you for including your attempt. Please remember to do so in the future :)

Comment: I removed my previous comment. I also updated your question to remove that *magnet*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex for that (but you need to use `Matcher` with that, not `matches()` since this will only match a part of the input string):

```
@\w+(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)
```

Or, to allow any characters (not just word ones):

```
@[^\s"]+(?=(?:[^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*$)");
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hW2vJ6/2)

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

- `@\w+` - matches a literal `@`, then a sequence of word characters (or `[^\s"]` will match non-whitespace and non-double quotes)
- `(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)` - is a positive look-ahead that makes sure there is 0 or more...

  - `[^"]` - characters other than `"` or
  - `"[^"]*"` - `"`, then 0 or more characters other than `"`, and again `"` (so, just a phrase inside double quotes)
  - `$` - up to the end of string.

Sample code:

```
String EXAMPLE_TEST = "\"they used to have journalistic integrity... what happened\" @cbcnews";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("@\\w+(?=(?:[^\"]|\"[^\"]*\")*$)");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);
if (matcher.find()) {
     System.out.println("Found!");
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/xYDnBc)

Comment: Thank u  when I try this it works but the problem is it reurn found when I try it with this sentence : EXAMPLE_TEST = "\"they used to have journalistic integrity... what happened @cbcnews\""; which should not since @cbcnews is inside quotations, so for more explanation I want it to return found when @+whatever that contains news is out side double quotations

Comment: It is because of `\S`, change to `\w`. You can also use [`@[^\s"]+` instead](http://ideone.com/bes6Uv).

Comment: Thank u a lot for ur awesome answer :)